# How can i sort list according to variable numbers

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting, contains

I created a list and the list has variable values. I want to sort this list by the variable values.

I need the order to be set by `stBirthday` decreasing order and add textbox
`stBirthday` values like *11081990* , *07051993* , *01012001* but changing.

```
string stName = null;
string stSurname = null;
int stBirthday = 0;
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        myList.Add(stName + stSurname + stBirthDay);
}
private void List_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        textBox1.Text += myList[i];
}
```

for example, list values;

```
mylist[0]= "Johnnie" + "Black" + 03041993
mylist[1]= "Gregory" + "Elliott" + 28071997
mylist[2]= "Kristopher" + "Bridges" + 11231998
mylist[3]= "Olive" + "Higgins" + 05122001
```

i want to sort like that

```
"Gregory" + "Elliott" + 28071997
"Kristopher" + "Bridges" + 11231998
"Olive" + "Higgins" + 05122001
"Johnnie" + "Black" + 03041993
```

sort by stBirthday value = 28071997 > 11231998 > 05122001 > 03041993

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`. It's been deprecated for a long time. `List<T>` is much better.

Comment: Also, you should probably use a custom class to hold the related data, like `public class Person { public string FirstName { get; set; } public string Last Name { get; set; } public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; } }` and then you can create a `var people = new List<Person>();` and once that's created you can do: `var orderedPeople = people.OrderByDescending(person => person.DateOfBirth).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

convert to date before you sort, then you will get the expected result,  currently you are sorting an int

Comment: This isn't a very good answer without an example of how to accomplish your suggestion, because it leads to the next question, *"How do I convert an `int` to a `DateTime`?"*. Consider adding a code sample or move it to the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is the one, Rufus provided. C# is object oriented. You could achieve the same thing with strings, sorting with a linq-expression and Regex, but that is really awkward. After ordering the List, you can do something like:

```cs
public class Person 
{ 
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; } 
} 

var people = new List<Person>(); 
/* adding people comes here */

// sorting
var orderedPeople = people.OrderByDescending(person => 
                    person.DateOfBirth);
textBox1.Text = String.Join(" ", 
               from p in orderedPeople 
               select p.FirstName+p.LastName+p.DateOfBirth.ToString("ddMMyyyy")
               );
```